# Combobox in repeater, unique selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I have a combobox inside a data repeater,
I need to remove the selected value of a combobox from the rest of the repeated comboboxes so I can forbid multiple selection of the same value in more than one combobox:

if combobox1 selected value is 'john smith' I need to remove 'john smith' from the other repeated comboboxes. Any help ?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTableMapper" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsSQLColumnNames"
    OnItemDataBound="rptTableMapper_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table width="500px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbCsvColumns" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbCsvColumns_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                    </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and the code behind is

```
protected void cmbCsvColumns_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = ((ASPxComboBox)(sender)).ClientID;
    string text = ((ASPxComboBox)(sender)).Text;
    for (int i = 0; i < rptTableMapper.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        ASPxComboBox cmb = (ASPxComboBox)(rptTableMapper.Items[i].FindControl("cmbCsvColumns"));
        ListEditItem selectedItem = ((ASPxComboBox)(sender)).SelectedItem;
        if (cmb.ClientID != s)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Guess you forgot to paste the code.

Comment: the code is basic. a combobox inside a repeater !

Comment: cmbCsvColumns_SelectedIndexChanged code please

Comment: "I need to remove the selected value of a combobox from the rest of the repeated comboboxes"  means u have more than combobox in ur repeater

Comment: it's a repeater, it will repeat the same combobox but under different clientId

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that if it is your business requirement or what but my suggestion is not to remove the entry from drop down.
Lets say in Row 1 user selected value 1, so Value 1 is removed from other drop downs in remaining rows, in Row 2 user selects value 2, which is also removed for the remaining ones. Now in row 1 user selects value 3, now you will have to remove the value 3 from remaining dropdowns and also add value 1 back in them.

My suggestion is to call a javascript method and hold your selected values in javascript, if user selects a value that is already selected, simply give him an alert that you have already selected this value. Through this approach you can reduce the server side postbacks as well, if you are doing postback only to remove the values.
so your solution should be like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTableMapper" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsSQLColumnNames"
                OnItemDataBound="rptTableMapper_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table width="500px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbCsvColumns" onchange="cmbCsvColumns_SelectedIndexChanged(this);"
                                    runat="server" AutoPostBack="False">
                                </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

and your javascript should be like:

```
var selectedValues = "";
function cmbCsvColumns_SelectedIndexChanged(obj)
{
    if(selectedValues.indexOf(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value + ",") != -1)
    {
        alert("Your message");
    }
    else
        selectedValues = selectedValues + e.options[e.selectedIndex].value + ",";

}
```

You have to enhance the javascript method a little bit to avoid issues like matching of "1," in "11,"

I have used an asp:dropdown in repeater and on server side you can acheive it like:

```
protected void cmbCsvColumns_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = ((DropDownList)(sender)).ClientID;

        for (int i = 0; i < rptTableMapper.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList cmb = (DropDownList)(rptTableMapper.Items[i].FindControl("cmbCsvColumns"));
            ListItem selectedItem = ((DropDownList)(sender)).SelectedItem;
            if (cmb.ClientID != s)
            {
                foreach (ListItem li in cmb.Items)
                {
                    if (li.Value == selectedItem.Value)
                    {
                        cmb.Items.Remove(li);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

The thing that you have to handle it is that if an item removed from dropdown is unselected than how to add it back in the other drop downs.

Comment: Thank you Imran, 
What I am trying to achieve is an SQL -> csv table mapper that will map column names from SQL to their equivalent column names present in the header of the CSV. You can find a similar running example in SQL server, 
Right click on a database in Management Studio and click import data, select datasource as flatfile and pick CSV and the select an existing table name and click on edit mappings, see the behavior of the comboboxes. I believe we can do it without JS. Any additional information to help with this Dilema ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with server side code, kindly have a look at it.